# Using deeplinks to share User profile

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

Currently, I'm using firebase to store the users in the database but I wanted to add a link to each specific id so the user is able to copy their profile link and send it to a friend if they have the app or not, I read a little bit about dynamic links from the firebase as well, but still lacking the idea of how to connect a users profile to a deep link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap user id (or profile id) somehow like: link.co/user_id

In dynamic link handler method you have to get user id (or profile id) from link and send it to ProfileViewController, then you simply open it as you always do from other place in application.

There's good article to read how exactly you will do this: https://www.yudiz.com/deep-linking-in-ios-using-firebase/

Comment: I'll see what I can do.